# Регулярные выражения. Проверка на валидный HEX цвет

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Только начал изучать регулярные выражения и не совсем понимаю как они работают и как правильно их тестировать((

```js
const getHexadecimalColors = str => {
    const hexColor = /#([a-f0-9]{6}|[a-f0-9]{3})/gi;
    return str.match(hexColor);
};

console.log(
  getHexadecimalColors('color: #3f3; background-color: #AA00ef; and: #abcd')
);
```

я указал, чтобы проверялось на буквы от a до f и цифры от 0 до 9, которые повторяются 6 или 3 раза. Почему проходит валидацию #abcd? Как сделать так, чтобы строка из 4 символов не проходила проверку?

Comment: Вы даже `match` не вызвали.

Comment: Машинально. Исправил

Comment: Как я посмотрел единственным вариантом остаётся обыкновенные методы с JS, т.к. негативный просмотр вперёд не прошёл, негативный просмотр назад тоже не прошёл. Как вариант просто проводить через валидацию все подобные строки, а потом уже через `filter` проверять длину и оставлять только с длиной 7 и 4 (Учитываем `#` тоже). Вот кстати регулярка: `/#([a-f0-9]+)/gi` (для любой длины).

Comment: Спасибо! Пошел разбираться, что такое \b))

Answer (score 1):

Валидацию проходит не `#abcd`, а `#abc`. Потому что там "три буквы от а до f или цифры от 0 до 9". Точно так же пройдет валидацию строка из 7 и более таких знаков, т.к. в неё умещается подстрока из 6. Вам надо в конце регулярного выражения поставить знак конца слова - `\b`

```js
const getHexadecimalColors = str => {
    const hexColor = /#([a-f0-9]{6}|[a-f0-9]{3})\b/gi;
    return str.match(hexColor);
};

console.log(
  getHexadecimalColors('color: #3f3; background-color: #AA00ef; and: #abcd')
);
```